# How to define redis client globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a simple component that is bind to a controller. So every HTTP request calls testFunction():

```
//test.js
const redisHelper = require('../myRedis');

class TEST {

  testFunction() {
    ....
      redisHelper.getCache(cacheKey)
        .then((cacheData) => {
          ....
  }
}

module.exports = TEST;
```

This component requires myRedis module:

```
//myRedis.js
const redis = require('redis');

class myRedis {

  constructor () {
    ....
    this.redisClient = this.getRedisClient();
  }

  getRedisClient () {
    let redisClient;
    ....

    return redisClient;
  }

  getCache (key) {
    ....
  }

  quit () {
    this.redisClient.quit();
  }
}

module.exports = new myRedis();
```

I don't want to create redis client for every HTTP request but keep it ON/open. So can I declare redis client in app.js and use it in test.js? Then on process exit I'll close the connection.

> ```
> process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
>   server.close(() => {
>     redisClient.quit();
>     process.exit();
>   })
> })
> ```

The problem is with redis client that crashes when it's open/close for every of thousands HTTP requests

Comment: Looks to me like your problem is you are opening a connection per request but not closing, well, any. The rule of thumb for the majority of data source connections is open late and close early.

Comment: I don't want to close connection at all but just when apps exit or crash. Not just redis but any other db connection mongo/postgres, etc.. By opening and closing for every HTTP request makes app crash for thousands concurrent requests

Comment: so then I question your setup, these services are designed to handle thousands of concurrent requests. IMO you would want to open a Redis connection when appropriate (presumably not every request needs access to Redis) and close as soon as you're done. Could you show a full example of what code doesn't work? The code above isn't really a complete example.

Comment: I thought keeping Redis connections open is favorable in some cases: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/568#issuecomment-38082445

Comment: I cannot show you complete code. I'm just asking about best practice. Let's assume each request needs redis access. So instead opening/closing it for each request why don't just keep it always open and define it globally in app.js?

Comment: In that case, yes, it would make sense to reuse a global connection but there are lots of factors to consider e.g. who else is accessing Redis? How much traffic are you expecting? etc.

Comment: the app redis client will just read/set db data. Expected thousands connections per minute. So what's the better implementation ?

Comment: Thousands of connections per minute? It would definitely make sense to use a global connection

Comment: Thank you James. This is what I need. So how do I convert my code? I need to make sure it's stable if it's open globally and I can close it properly on app exit

Comment: Closing on `SIGTERM` looks a decent approach to me, probably want to to also catch `SIGINT` for development scenarios.